# What does it mean for commutator of position and momentum to be equal to the metric tensor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, metric-tensor, commutator

I was reading: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505152

And got confused by the first line stating

$$ [P^{\mu}, X^{\nu}] = ig^{\mu\nu} \tag{1.1}.$$

I want to believe that this a generalization of the statement

$$ XP - PX = i\hbar\mathbb{1}.$$

But I can't seem to guess what is meant by $g^{\mu \nu}$. I have seen this type of expression before as an expression for the metric tensor, wich makes me wonder if the expression $[P^{\mu}, X^{\nu}]$ is some kind of tensor product but again I've never heard of a out product of momentum and position being equal to the metric before, so that doesn't sit well with me.

How do I make sense of this?

Comment: The statement $PX-XP=i\hbar$ holds for 1d systems. In 3d systems one has $P^iX^j-X^jP^i=i\hbar \delta^{ij}$, where $\delta^{ij}=1$ if $i=j$, and $\delta^{ij}=0$ otherwise. Do you understand all these statements?

Comment: yes, $g^{\mu\nu}$ is meant to be the metric of your (generic) spacetime, and even if $x^\mu$ and $p^\nu$ were just numbers, their juxtaposition in a product $x^\mu p^\nu$ is a tensor product that produces a tensor of rank $(2,0)$ (i.e. with two contravariant indices, as $x^\mu$ has one contravariant index). If you have two operators things are a bit more complicated as $X^\mu$ doesn't just have a Lorentz structure but also an operatorial structure, but it's still true that $X^\mu P^\nu$ is an entity that transforms as a $(2,0)$ tensor. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My foreword is that IMHO that expression is wrong (EDIT: I'm too bold sometimes, let's say incomplete), as the right hand side is clearly symmetric in the interchange $\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$, while the left hand side is not, unless we impose by assumption that kind of symmetry, see below for more detail.

Nevertheless, let's forget it for a moment and focus on the purpose of the paragraph.

Basically, the paragraph wants to explain why Quantum Field Theory is the way it is, and not otherwise, in particular why do we have **fields** as operators and not anymore position $\vec x$, which has been underemployed as a simple parameter, together with time.

Indeed, Quantum Mechanics is a nonrelativistic theory, meaning that time and position are not dealt with on the same level, for example the first is a parameter while the second is an operator.

Reunite QM with Special or General relativity would mean that every 3-vector like position $\vec X$ and momentum $\vec P$ must be promoted to a 4-vector $X^\mu$ and $P^\mu$, and the commutation relations (which are the core of QM) must be extended as well.

The most natural extension would then be to take spatial momentum $\vec P$ and the Hamiltonian $H$ and build the 4-vector operator $(H,\vec P)$, and similarly for the position, to take time $t$, promoting it to an operator $T$, and build a four vector $(T,\vec X)$.

The next step is to generalize the commutation relations:

$$[X^\mu,P^\nu]=?$$

As $X^\mu$ and $P^\mu$ are 4-vectors, i.e. $(1,0)$ contravariant tensors, their product $X^\mu P^\mu$ will be a $(2,0)$ contravariant tensor. If, as we said at the beginning, we assume that the amount of noncommutativity which exists between some direction $X^\mu$ and a momentum direction $P^\nu$, has no physical reason to be expected different from the amount of noncommutativity between some direction $X^\nu$ and a momentum direction $P^\mu$, then we conclude that $[X^\mu,P^\nu]$ must be a symmetric entity, so on the right hand side of $[X^\mu,P^\nu]$ there must lie some symmetric $(2,0)$ tensor.

In a generic spacetime which is endowed with a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and its beloved inverse $g^{\mu\nu}$, the best candidate to represent our commutation relations is exactly $g^{\mu\nu}$:

$$[X^\mu,P^\nu]=c\cdot g^{\mu\nu}\mathbb I$$

where $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator in the Hilbert space where the operators act.

The constant $c$ is determined considering that anyway $[X^\mu,P^\nu]$ is anti-Hermitian, and in case of flat spacetime the spatial commutation relations should yield the canonical $[X^i,P^j]=i\hbar\delta^{ij}$, so finally

$$[X^\mu,P^\nu]=i\hbar \cdot g^{\mu\nu}\mathbb I$$

This fact could be seen in a clearer way, without the need of handwavy arguments, if we consider the definition of $P^\mu$ as **the generator of infinitesimal translations**:

$$x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+dx^\mu$$

in terms of the position eigenbasis $|x^\mu\rangle$, we postulate the existence of an operator $\mathcal J(dx^\mu)$ such that:

$$\mathcal J(dx^\mu)|x^\mu\rangle=|x^\mu+dx^\mu\rangle$$

Following closely the same steps that you can find, for example, in Sakurai, and that lead to $[X^i,P^j]=i\hbar \delta^{ij}$, you will define an operator infinitesimally close to the identity, keeping only its first order in $dx^\mu$:

$$\mathcal J(dx^\mu)=\mathbb I-G(dx^\mu) +o(dx^\mu{}^2)$$

As $\mathcal J(dx^\mu)$ has not any free index, it is to be considered a **scalar**, so the operator $G(dx^\mu)$ must involve a combination of $P^\mu$ and $dx^\mu$ of this kind, i.e. a scalar product:

$$G(dx^\mu)=\frac{i P^\mu g_{\mu\nu}dx^\nu}{\hbar}$$

from which the generalization involving the (inverse of the) metric tensor.

Now, everything I said so far is completely useless, because the remainder of the paragraph explains that defining a $T$ operator violates a fundamental physical principle: the boundedness from below of the energy (and its quantization).

So, this way has to be discarded, and this is the main reason why in QFT, instead of having a 4-vector position operator, we have 4 parameters $(\vec x,t)$, i.e. $\vec x$ has been downgraded from operator to c-number.

Hope this helps

Comment: i appreciate the clarity of the answer. Quick question: the only part now that remains a mystery is "the best candidate to represent our commutation relations is exactly..." how is this decision made? So far we have established we need a symmetric (2,0) tensor, which reduces to $\delta_{ij}$ in flat space time, how is this enough information to deduce the metric tensor is necessary?

Comment: You're right, in principle one should consider the most general tensor combination that it's possible to build with other objects naturally present in the theory (i.e., the Riemann and Ricci tensors), then it would be physical considerations or experiments, or further assumptions to rule out terms. For example, I would guess that in this case terms containing derivative would be forbidden (i.e. further $P^\mu$) as usually commutation relations between $X$ and $P$ are assumed to be proportional to the identity.

Comment: But I don't mean at all to trivialize QFT in curved spacetime which is a beautiful and very complex theory, there would for sure be a better explanation of what I tried to say. In our case, anyway, there is an even simpler explanation which I added to my answer; tell me if it clarifies a bit